# Unable to connect Arduino Uno to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: arduino-uno

I've received an Arduino Uno today only. I have zero experience prior to Arduino boards or any other micro controller. I followed every step very carefully from the setting up guide for Linux based OS, but I still can't connect the board with my Ubuntu 16.04 PC. After googling the problem I found that the device must show up as `ttyACM*` but I don't see any such device in `/dev`. Its also not listed under the command `lsusb` but the LED's on the board are working properly. The ON LED is turned on when I connect it with my PC and the inbuilt LED starts to blink.

This is what the IDE displays:

[image: Arduino IDE]

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: yes I have two cables

Comment: @Majenko can you help me please

Comment: In a terminal, run `dmesg -w`. Then plug in the Arduino. Post the additional lines that should appear into your question.

Comment: Some things that may help you: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/diagnosing-arduino-problems-in-linux/

Comment: @Majenko I tried `dmesg -w` but no new lines show up when i connect the board

Comment: Is it a genuine Arduino or a Chinese clone?

Comment: @Majenko its a clone

Comment: Ah well, there you go then. Maybe it's just dead. Maybe you were sold a lemon.

Comment: @Majenko but it can't be dead the LEDs are working just fine

Comment: There are two parts: the main MCU, which is working, and the USB interface which, on clones, often dies. Does it have a square or a rectangular chip next to the USB socket?

Comment: @Majenko A rectangular one

Comment: CH340G - notoriously bad.

Comment: Did you select the port in the Tools menu? Check that it shows up there and is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add yourself to the dialout group in Ubuntu so that your user account can access the serial ports.

Then, in the Arduino IDE, the Tools->Port menu should show you options. Right now, the screenshot you gave shows that it's set for COM1, which is a Windows-style serial port naming and definitely won't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: I've already done that and the `Port` menu is grayed out.

Comment: Did you log out and log back in after adding yourself to the dialout group?

Comment: yes I did.
I even tried rebooting but nothing works